# PHPDoc, PHPStorm и Generator

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Здравствуйте. Как правильно описать возвращаемый тип метода в PHPDoc:

```
/**
 * @return \Generator
 */
public function getLayers()
{
    foreach($this->layers as $layer)
         yield $layer;
    }
}
```

При использовании в цикле, PHPStorm не понимает, какой тип он итерирует:

```
foreach ($this->getLayers() as $layer)
    $layer->... //PHPStorm: "я не знаю что это!"
```

При этом, если бы возвращался просто массив, можно было бы описать так:

```
/**
 * @return LayerType[]
 */
public function getLayers()
{
    return $this->layers;
}
```

Такой способ, при итерации распознает объекты.

Comment: Прочитайте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083184/best-way-to-document-phpdoc-generators-methods-that-yield#comment48406913_30083184  и http://stackoverflow.com/a/33272232/6104996  может быть поможет

Comment: Да, я читал уже. Думал, может есть более правильный способ. Сейчас, получается, что я обманываю конечного пользователя, говоря, что я возвращаю ему массив слоев, на самом деле возвращая генератор.

Comment: К сожалению, дженерики пока еще не подвезли

Comment: @Etki, скорее бы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно комбинировать типы, чтобы удовлетворить и читателя кода, и PhpStorm:

```
/**
 * @return \Generator|LayerType[]
 */
public function getLayers()
{
    foreach($this->layers as $layer)
         yield $layer;
    }
}
```

Небольшое дополнение. Такой синтаксис все же подразумевает, что функция может возвращать значения разных типов. Поэтому конкретно в этом случае причину его использования лучше дополнительно задокументировать, чтобы избежать неоднозначной трактовки.